# I need an epub to text solution in Python

Tags: python, epub

I need to get text from an epub

```
from epub_conversion.utils import open_book, convert_epub_to_lines

f = open("demofile.txt", "a")
book = open_book("razvansividra.epub")
lines = convert_epub_to_lines(book)
```

I use this but if I use print(lines) it does print only one line. And the library is 6 years old. Do you guys know a good way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about https://github.com/aerkalov/ebooklib

> EbookLib is a Python library for managing EPUB2/EPUB3 and Kindle
>   files. It's capable of reading and writing EPUB files programmatically
>   (Kindle support is under development).
>
> The API is designed to be as simple as possible, while at the same
>   time making complex things possible too. It has support for covers,
>   table of contents, spine, guide, metadata and etc.

```
import ebooklib
from ebooklib import epub

book = epub.read_epub('test.epub')

for doc in book.get_items_of_type(ebooklib.ITEM_DOCUMENT):
    print doc
```

Comment: As I saw, I can't find a way to get the text, only images and so on.

Comment: Now, i'm getting this type of format            <EpubHtml:item_e150af44-adae-484d-a000-a659b2a7139f:chapters/e150af44-adae-484d-a000-a659b2a7139f.xhtml>Now, i'm getting this type of format            <EpubHtml:item_e150af44-adae-484d-a000-a659b2a7139f:chapters/e150af44-adae-484d-a000-a659b2a7139f.xhtml>  And there is no text at all

Comment: @Adrian you can use doc.content to access the text

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **sloppy** script that extracts the text from an .epub in the right order. Improvements could be made

**Quick explanation:**

- Takes input(epub) and output(txt) file paths as first and second arguments
- Extracts epub content in temporary directory
- Parses 'content.opf' file for xhtml content and order
- Extracts text from each xhtml

*Dependency: lxml*

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import shutil, os, sys, zipfile, tempfile
from lxml import etree

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} <input.epub> <output.txt>")
    exit(1)

inputFilePath=sys.argv[1]
outputFilePath=sys.argv[2]

print(f"Input: {inputFilePath}")
print(f"Output: {outputFilePath}")

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpDir:
    print(f"Extracting input to temp directory '{tmpDir}'.")
    with zipfile.ZipFile(inputFilePath, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(tmpDir)

    with open(outputFilePath, "w") as outFile:
        print(f"Parsing 'container.xml' file.")
        containerFilePath=f"{tmpDir}/META-INF/container.xml"
        tree = etree.parse(containerFilePath)
        for rootFilePath in tree.xpath( "//*[local-name()='container']"
                                        "/*[local-name()='rootfiles']"
                                        "/*[local-name()='rootfile']"
                                        "/@full-path"):
            print(f"Parsing '{rootFilePath}' file.")
            contentFilePath = f"{tmpDir}/{rootFilePath}"
            contentFileDirPath = os.path.dirname(contentFilePath)

            tree = etree.parse(contentFilePath)
            for idref in tree.xpath("//*[local-name()='package']"
                                    "/*[local-name()='spine']"
                                    "/*[local-name()='itemref']"
                                    "/@idref"):
                for href in tree.xpath( f"//*[local-name()='package']"
                                        f"/*[local-name()='manifest']"
                                        f"/*[local-name()='item'][@id='{idref}']"
                                        f"/@href"):
                    outFile.write("\n")
                    xhtmlFilePath = f"{contentFileDirPath}/{href}"
                    subtree = etree.parse(xhtmlFilePath, etree.HTMLParser())
                    for ptag in subtree.xpath("//html/body/*"):
                        for text in ptag.itertext():
                            outFile.write(f"{text}")
                        outFile.write("\n")

print(f"Text written to '{outputFilePath}'.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Epublib has the problem of modifying your epub metadata, so if you want the original file with maybe only a few things changed you can simply unpack the epub into a directory and parse it with Beautifulsoup:

First, install BeautifulSoup by:

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

Then use the following code:

```
from os import path, listdir
from zipfile import ZipFile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


FILE_NAME = "YOUR_FILE_NAME"
extract_dir = "EXTRACT_DIRECTORY"

with ZipFile(FILE_NAME, "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(extract_dir)

for filename in listdir(extract_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".xhtml"): 
        print(filename)
        with open(path.join(extract_dir, filename), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "lxml")
            for text_object in soup.find_all(text=True): 
                print(text_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

convert_epub_to_lines returns an iterator to lines, which you need to iterate one by one to get.

Instead, you can get all lines with "convert", see in the documentation of the library:

https://pypi.org/project/epub-conversion/

Comment: The library is not maintained anymore!

Comment: Hey got an error, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml_cleaner'

Comment: @ScipioAfricanus you can resolve this error by installing it with `pip install xml_cleaner`